# QML canvas stroke with different line thickness on few parts

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, stroke

I've created following QML item which defines custom shape. I'm trying to get that shape with same line thickness while few segments are bigger than the others.

```
    Item {
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 400
    height:400
    Canvas {
        x: 10
        y: 10
        anchors.margins: 10
        readonly property int widthMultiplier: 11
        readonly property int heightMultiplier: 9
        readonly property int baseValue: 30
        readonly property int topCornerFirstMultiplier: 3
        readonly property int topCornerSecondMultiplier: 3
        readonly property int bottomCornerFirstMultiplier: 8
        readonly property int bottomCornerSecondMultiplier: 6
        anchors.fill:parent


        onPaint: {
            var context = getContext("2d");

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, baseValue*topCornerFirstMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(0, baseValue*heightMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(baseValue*bottomCornerFirstMultiplier, baseValue*heightMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(baseValue*widthMultiplier, baseValue*bottomCornerSecondMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(baseValue*widthMultiplier, 0);
            context.lineTo(baseValue*topCornerSecondMultiplier, 0);
            context.lineTo(0, baseValue*topCornerFirstMultiplier);


            context.lineWidth = 3
            context.strokeStyle = "black"
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
}
```

The shape that I get looks is following:
[Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOZsH.png)

Comment: What is the question? Does the shape differ from your expectation, if so how? Or is there some other problem with the code you want help with?

Comment: The question is that two lines (left one and top one) have different thickness. Can I fix that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The line appear to be a different width because they are being drawn outside the canvas region (and hence are not partially visible). For example the vertical line drawn by

```
            context.moveTo(0, baseValue*topCornerFirstMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(0, baseValue*heightMultiplier);
```

is drawn just at the edge of the canvas so half of it is not visible. To solve this issue you can manually add a little padding. In your case I just replaced the 0 x and y values with 5 and the shape is drawn as expected.

```
            context.moveTo(5, baseValue*topCornerFirstMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(5, baseValue*heightMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(baseValue*bottomCornerFirstMultiplier, baseValue*heightMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(baseValue*widthMultiplier, baseValue*bottomCornerSecondMultiplier);
            context.lineTo(baseValue*widthMultiplier, );
            context.lineTo(baseValue*topCornerSecondMultiplier, 5);
            context.lineTo(5, baseValue*topCornerFirstMultiplier);
```

Comment: If I had not read this answer, I would be looking for the problem in very different places. It worked, thanks